# Moving focus from one EditText to another

Tags: java, android, xml, focus, android-edittext

I designed a layout for a create account activity.

when one `EditText` loses focus, I'm doing some checking on the input and if something is not right I want to regain the focus on that `EditText`.

I already saw some questions about this, but its not working for me (or I'm doing something wrong).

when I touch on a different EditText which triggers the requestFocus(), the focus remains on the current `EditText` and another focus icon is shown in the `EditText` which requeted the focus.

help please

here's my layout file:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.cellap.tq"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:focusable="true" 
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
android:background="@drawable/create_account_background" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:focusable="true" 
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="70dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp">

    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/userTextView"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#F4DFA7"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:text="Username"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/userEditText"
        android:inputType="text|textEmailAddress"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"

        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:maxLength="64"
        android:background="@drawable/edit_text"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|right"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white">

    </EditText>
</LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:focusable="true" 
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true" 
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp">

        <TextView 
            android:id="@+id/passTextView"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:textColor="#F4DFA7"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:text="Password"/>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/passEditText"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="30dp"

            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:maxLength="30"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:background="@drawable/edit_text">


        </EditText>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:focusable="true" 
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp">

        <TextView 
            android:id="@+id/passConfirmTextView"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:textColor="#F4DFA7"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:text="Confirm password"/>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/passConfirmEditText"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="30dp"

            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:maxLength="30"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            android:background="@drawable/edit_text"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white">


        </EditText>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:focusable="true" 
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp">

        <TextView 
            android:id="@+id/emailTextView"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:textColor="#F4DFA7"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:text="Email"/>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/emailEditText"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="30dp"

            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:maxLength="255"
            android:scrollHorizontally="false" 
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
            android:background="@drawable/edit_text"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white">


        </EditText>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" 
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp">

        <TextView 
            android:id="@+id/confirmEmailTextView"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:textColor="#F4DFA7"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:text="Confirm email"/>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/confirmEmailEditText"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="30dp"

            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:maxLength="255"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
            android:background="@drawable/edit_text"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white">


        </EditText>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" 
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp">

        <TextView 
            android:id="@+id/signupTextView"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:textColor="#F4DFA7"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:text="Sign up:"/>

        <TextView 
            android:id="@+id/signUpText"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:textColor="#FF0000"
            android:paddingRight="5dp"

            />



    </LinearLayout>


    <com.cellap.tq.ButtonView
        android:id="@+id/create_btn"
         android:layout_width="216dp"
        android:layout_height="49dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        custom:button="create_btn"/>


    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="30dp">

        <Button 
            android:id="@+id/fbconnect_btn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/fbconnect_btn"/>

    </LinearLayout>
```

in the code I do like that:

```
final EditText userEditText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.userEditText);

    userEditText.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            if(!hasFocus){
                Log.i(TAG, "userEditText lost focus");

                m_userName = userEditText.getText().toString();
                if(m_userName.length() < 6){
                    m_signUpText.setText("Username should have at least 6 characters");
                    userEditText.requestFocus();
                }
                else{
                    checkUserNameExists();
                }

            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: just do  yourEditText.requestFocus();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

found a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6968924/843227)

This solution works (no need to add android:focusable="true"\android:focusableInTouchMode="true"):

```
final EditText userEditText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.userEditText);

userEditText.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {

    @Override
    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
        if(!hasFocus){
            Log.i(TAG, "userEditText lost focus");
            if(null == m_requestFocus){
                m_userName = userEditText.getText().toString();
                if(m_userName.length() < 6){
                    m_signUpText.setText("Username should have at least 6 characters");
                    m_requestFocus = userEditText;
                }
                else{
                    checkUserNameExists();
                }
            }
        }
        else{
            if(null != m_requestFocus & m_requestFocus != userEditText){
                v.clearFocus();
                m_requestFocus.requestFocus();
                m_requestFocus = null;
            }
        }
    }
});
```

To clarify the problem:

User edits EditText A -> user touch EditText B to edit it -> EditText A onFocusListener.onFocusChanged is called -> EditText A requestFocus -> EditText B still has the focus and typing any text, writes to its edit text. only a marker of focus, appears on EditText A.

Answer (score 6):

You can listen on this action `EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_NEXT` for the first EditText and then request focus to the second one by this call `requestFocus()`, this is an example:

```
firstEditText.setOnEditorActionListener(new OnEditorActionListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId,
                KeyEvent event) {

            if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_NEXT) {
                secondEditText.requestFocus();
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all why do you provide

`android:focusable="true" 
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"`

to layout, not to `EditText` field?

Second - `requestFocus()` definition from dev.andro:
"Call this to **try to** give focus to a specific view or to one of its descendants."

Conclusion will be a question, because I poorly understood what you've said. This is working, focus is staying in `userEditText` but some other `EditText` is having selector for focused View?

Comment: I provided that because thats what I saw in some answer to similar question. it does the same if i don't provide it.

i don't understand what you mean by selector, but the edit my question to clarify it.

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14273445/656927) works for me, and it looks less hackish.

What is done is send the requestFocus() in a Runnable to the process message queue. Differently from the link above, I didn't need to clear the focus of the other field and didn't need to postDelayed. My code

```
        new Handler().post(new Runnable() {

              @Override
              public void run() {
                   ev1.requestFocus();
              }
        });
```