# Can two views both have focus in Android

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-popupwindow

I have a EditText, and a popupWindown(which has a ListView in it), now i touch the EditText, the popupWindow shows.

i need the situation:  i can input something in SoftInput, and i also can click a child item in ListView which is the children of PopupWindow.

Now, i can only input, or can only click listview , i can't do the both thing in Android 4.1, 4.2. But i can do both in Android 4.4, 5.0。

I tried in many ways, like popupWindo.setFocus(true), which only make the EditText lose the focus.

So, Can android allow two views both have focus ?

Comment: no two view can't have focus at same time

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, two (or more) views cannot have focus at the same time, not possible.

**[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3003062/focus-issue-with-multiple-edittexts/6968924#6968924)** is how to change focus from one textView to another textView. Which you could change in your case.

Comment: your solution do not work for me, i need they both has focus. I now was planing some other ways. I think maybe the editText cannot work fine with popupWindow and ListView, maybe i could change the ListView to a dynamic LiearLayou. I am trying.

Comment: There is no way for to views to have focus simultaneously! You could compare it to clicking two buttons at the same time with the mouse.

Answer (score 3):

Actually, technically speaking two views **can** have focus at the same time - not just as you would imagine (and as you would need for your usecase):

The parents of a focused view can also have their focus set to true. Cf. an excerpt from an example view hierarchy, `has-focus=true` pops out more than once:

```
View Hierarchy:
+>DecorView{id=-1, visibility=VISIBLE, width=1920, height=1080, has-focus=true, has-focusable=true, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, 
|
+->LinearLayout{id=-1, visibility=VISIBLE, width=1776, height=1080, has-focus=true, has-focusable=true, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=fal
|
+-->ViewStub{id=16909243, res-name=action_mode_bar_stub, visibility=GONE, width=0, height=0, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-f
|
+-->FrameLayout{id=-1, visibility=VISIBLE, width=1776, height=1008, has-focus=true, has-focusable=true, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=fal
|
+--->FitWindowsLinearLayout{id=2131296268, res-name=action_bar_root, visibility=VISIBLE, width=1776, height=1008, has-focus=true, has-focusable
|
+---->ViewStubCompat{id=2131296279, res-name=action_mode_bar_stub, visibility=GONE, width=0, height=0, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, ha
|
+---->ContentFrameLayout{id=16908290, res-name=content, visibility=VISIBLE, width=1776, height=1008, has-focus=true, has-focusable=true, has-wi
|
+----->LinearLayout{id=-1, visibility=VISIBLE, width=1776, height=1008, has-focus=true, has-focusable=true, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable
|
+------>RecyclerView{id=2131296483, res-name=lstRecordings, visibility=VISIBLE, width=1776, height=873, has-focus=true, has-focusable=true, has
```