# Highlight entire row in listView

Tags: java, android, listview

I have custom row in my `listView` containts `LinearLayout` with two `EditView`

I want highlight both `EditView`

```
list.postDelayed(new Runnable()
    {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            list.getChildAt(0).requestFocus();
        }
    },200);
```

It doesn't work because highlight only one `EditText`

How can I highlight both?

Comment: Like request focus on both? Or have them both enabled?

Comment: but how to do this? Some example?

Comment: @Brandon I've tried get both `EditView` and call requestFocus, but of course it is not work, because only second is highlighted.

Comment: This is because you can only have focus on a single view at a time, from another SO question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27289381/can-two-views-both-have-focus-in-android), "No, two (or more) views cannot have focus at the same time, not possible."

Comment: you have to highlight your linearlayout instead of edittexts

Answer (score 0):

You can't focus more than 1 object at a time.
However, you can draw an EditText as it was focused.

For doing that, use a `selector` and change colours for different states like `state_focused`.

or

you can use a style like this

```
<style name="EdThem" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/primary</item>
    <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/primary</item>
    <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/primary</item>
</style>
```

And EditText

```
<EditText
    ...
    android:theme="@style/EdThem">
</EditText>
```