# Issue while trying to focus on an EditText

Tags: android, android-edittext, focus

Actually i'm trying to make an app for devices with or without physical keyboard.

I've added a setOnEditorActionListener on my first editText and when actionDone is pressed or Enter button is pressed on a physical keyboard it should make visible the other editText and focus on it but it doesn't focusing on it.

Here is my OnEditorActionListner method:

```
  public void codeText(){
        code.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onEditorAction(TextView textView, int i, KeyEvent keyEvent) {
                if(i == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE || keyEvent.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER){
                    if(!code.getText().toString().equals("")){
                        if (TextUtils.isDigitsOnly(code.getText())) {
                            if (code.getText().length() >= 1 && code.getText().length() <= 999999) {
                                qtaBox.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                qtaText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                qta.requestFocus();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                return true;
            }
        });
    }
```

Full xml code, the editText from which i'm trying to focus is barcodeTxt the edittext i'm trying to focus is qtaTxt

```
     <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    tools:context=".SettingsActivity">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/logo"
        android:layout_margin="2dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        app:cardBackgroundColor="#001F54"
        app:cardCornerRadius="5dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        app:cardElevation="4dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            tools:ignore="UseCompoundDrawables">

            <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.2"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:id="@+id/backButton"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                android:src="@drawable/arrowback"
                android:background="#00454545"
                android:padding="8dp"
                tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:textAlignment="textEnd"
                android:text="INVENTARIO"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                tools:ignore="HardcodedText,RtlCompat" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                android:id="@+id/imageView"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.2"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="end"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:src="@drawable/storage"
                tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

        </LinearLayout>


    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>


    <LinearLayout
        android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/logo"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="20dp"
        android:background="#001f54"
        android:orientation="vertical">


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/barcodeText"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="12sp"
    android:layout_marginStart="3dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
    android:text="Barcode:"
    android:textColor="#b1b1b1"
    tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/barcodeBox"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        app:cardBackgroundColor="#01358f"
        app:cardCornerRadius="5dp"
        app:cardElevation="4dp">


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            tools:ignore="UselessLeaf">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="end"
                android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:src="@drawable/barcodesticker"
                android:tint="#ffffff"
                tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />


            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/barcodeTxt"
                android:selectAllOnFocus="true"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:imeOptions="actionDone"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:focusable="true"
                tools:ignore="Autofill,LabelFor" />


        </LinearLayout>


    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textQuantity"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="3dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
            android:text="Quantità:"
            android:textColor="#b1b1b1"
            tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/qtaBox"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        app:cardBackgroundColor="#a78824"
        app:cardCornerRadius="5dp"
        app:cardElevation="4dp">


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            tools:ignore="UselessLeaf">

            <TextView
                android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:text="QTA"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />


            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/qtaTxt"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:imeOptions="actionDone"
                android:maxLength="4"
                android:selectAllOnFocus="true"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:focusable="true"
                tools:ignore="Autofill,LabelFor" />


        </LinearLayout>



    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textLast"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="3dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
            android:text="Ultimo articolo letto:"
            android:textColor="#b1b1b1"
            tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:id="@+id/last"
            app:cardBackgroundColor="#c800544e"
            app:cardCornerRadius="5dp"
            app:cardElevation="0dp">



            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                tools:ignore="UselessLeaf">


                <ImageView
                    android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
                    android:layout_width="40dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_gravity="end"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/barcodesticker"
                    android:tint="#ffffff"
                    tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/lastBarCode"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:text=""
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:text="QTA"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/lastQta"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="0.3"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:text=""
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

            </LinearLayout>


        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>


        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            app:cardBackgroundColor="#e3008f43"
            app:cardCornerRadius="5dp"
            app:cardElevation="0dp">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnConferma"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:text="CONFERMA"
                android:background="#00001f54"
                tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    </LinearLayout>






    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/buttonBox"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_margin="2dp"
        app:cardBackgroundColor="#001F54"
        app:cardCornerRadius="5dp"
        app:cardElevation="4dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            tools:ignore="UseCompoundDrawables">

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/itemList"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="0.2"
                android:background="#00454545"
                android:padding="8dp"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                android:src="@drawable/history"
                tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

            <View
                android:id="@+id/divider"
                android:layout_width="1dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
                android:background="@drawable/gradient_separator"
                tools:ignore="DuplicateIds,InefficientWeight,NestedWeights" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/sendBtn"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="0.2"
                android:background="#00454545"
                android:padding="8dp"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                android:src="@drawable/send"
                tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />


        </LinearLayout>


    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Please put up a break point and see if it is entering `qta.requestFocus();` this line\

Comment: @UmangBurman yes it's entering it it but doesn't focus...

Comment: Okay. Can you show the xml code pls

Comment: @UmangBurman added full xml code from the activity

Comment: In my opinion, You java code is correct. The problem is that the `EditText` in which you are trying to set the focus is in another layout than that of the Source `EditText`. Try to put both `EditText` in a single layout and test your code. It will Work.

Comment: @UmangBurman could i make it focus anyway in different layouts? because in my java code i'm hidding the boxes with that edittext and making them visible so ill have to change a large part of java

Comment: I'm sorry, I lack knowledge on this. But, um, this might help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22862803/9763253

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be requesting focus to the `qta` reference instead of your `EditText` element. So maybe first try to do `qtaText.requestFocus()`.

If that didn't fix it, there might be something wrong with your XML config. While not being an expert on the topic, I do have a focusable `EditText` element in my latest project, where the XML looks like this:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/email"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fontFamily="@font/opensans_light"
    android:hint="@string/prompt_email"
    android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
    android:keepScreenOn="true"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
```

Hope this helps you solve the issue.

Comment: qta equals to qtaText as it's initialized onCreate as  qta = findViewById(R.id.qtaTxt);